# Blocking test for receivers

Tags: communication, receiver

In a receiver blocking test, I always see the description that "the test is peformed at a signal level 3dB above the required sensitivity". So what is meant by testing the receiver at "3dB above the required sensitivity"? And why this 3dB is the benchmark for the blocking test?

Comment: Phae Leung - Are you finished with this question or do you need some more explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *So what is meant by testing the receiver at "3dB above the required
> sensitivity"? And why this 3dB is the benchmark for the blocking test?*

"Receiver sensitivity" is how small an antenna signal it can successfully demodulate to produce an adequately recovered signal i.e. a received message with a fairly reasonable signal-to-noise ratio.

So, if you set the input antenna's radio signal at 3 dB above this limit, you are assured of a decent demodulated signal. It should be noted that 3 dB is a doubling of the power received by the antenna.

Comment: thanks, but how is this "3dB" related to the receiver blocking test?

Comment: don't know if one can transfer that to receivers, but in ADC design achieving 3db above the theoretical noise-floor is considered a good design. Also in communication systems you normally want your signal to have a noise margin to the minimum detectable signal. That is your design goal, you not want to undercut anyway. As 3dB is just such a common value, I guess its chosen. You may also choose 2 or 4 if you want, but 3dB is just more common.

Comment: The 3 dB level above the base minimum level of the receiver is to ensure that it is fed a wanted signal of twice the power that it can barely detect/demod adequately @PhaeLeung. If it wasn't set at this level then any extra disturbance due to a blocking signal would immediately degrade the detection and modulation and this wouldn't be a fair test. 3 dB is of course arbitrary but it does need to be present and 3 dB is a doubling of the received antenna power and is a "factor" that is often used.

Comment: Thanks for all the reply

Comment: @PhaeLeung are you done with this question now or do you still need clarification?

Comment: @Andyaka I understand this question now. Thanks.

Comment: [What you should consider doing next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png).

Comment: @PhaeLeung are you satisfied with this answer or do you need some more explanation?

Comment: @PhaeLeung are you satisfied with this answer or do you need some more explanation?

Comment: @PhaeLeung are you satisfied with this answer or do you need some more explanation?

Comment: @PhaeLeung are you satisfied with this answer or do you need some more explanation?

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks. I am satisfied with the answer.

Comment: @PhaeLeung then why haven't you formally accepted it?

Comment: @Andyaka accepted. Thanks.